# Why is there a start argument in Python's built-in sum function?

Tags: python

In the **sum** function, the prototype is **sum(iterable[,start])**, which sums everything in the iterable object plus the start value. I wonder why there is a start value in here? Is there nay particular use case this value is needed?

Please don't give any more examples how start is used. I am wondering why it exist in this function. If the prototype of sum function is only sum(iterable), and return None if iterable is empty, everything will just work. So why we need start in here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are summing things that aren't integers you may need to provide a start value to avoid an error.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedeltas = [timedelta(1), timedelta(2)]

>>> sum(timedeltas)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

>>> sum(timedeltas, timedelta())
datetime.timedelta(3)
```

Comment: And more generally `sum` is a kind of [foldr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) function which might require an initial value (*z* in the Wikipedia article).

Comment: That is because start is default to 0, and timedelta cannot add int. If originally there is no start param, no problem will exist in here. So why there is a start param after all?

Comment: Because otherwise, what do you add the first element to?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, @ziliangdotme: sum() can be implemented without adding the first element to anything. The real problem is that without a `start` argument, you face a dilemma deciding what to return if the iterable is empty.

Comment: Another example that I personally love is when you have `[[1, 2 , 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` and you want `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. You can do a simple `sum([[1, 2 , 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [])` to join all the lists on a list.

Comment: @razpeita you don't need a [] in here, the lists will sum up by themselves.

Comment: @ziliangdotme: Are you sure about that? It doesn't work for me without the `[]`.

Comment: @Mark it doesn't work because start is default to 0. It there is no start param, everything will be just fine.

Comment: @ziliangdotme: If there isn't a start parameter, what would it start with?

Comment: @Mark Can't it just sum within the iterable object?

Comment: @ziliangdotme: Not necessarily. Imagine if there were a character type (there isn't in Python, but just play along for the sake of example). `sum(['a', 'b'], '')` would give `'ab'` but treating the characters as integers, i.e. `sum(['a', 'b'], 0)` would give 195. If you don't have a start param, how would you be able to choose how to add? Also, what should the result of `sum([])` be?

Comment: @Mark yes, that is a little convincing now :)

Comment: @JohnMachin's answer about the empty iterable is the only thing that makes sense. Using the first element as start value by default would have been nicer otherwise, I think. For example when adding `Counter`s together, you have to do this: `sum(counters, start=Counter())` when `sum(counters)` would have been so much nicer.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo You're right, this answer didn't actually answer the question, and so far there isn't a good answer other than "it's always been like this". A pythonic way to handle an empty iterable would be to raise an error like Python does for an empty string in join.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo There is precisely the function that you are asking for. E.g., `functools.reduce(operator.add, an_iterable)` would sum `an_iterable`, and raise `TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value` if `an_iterable` is empty. Arguably, this is much cleaner; and maybe for consistency, `sum` should have done the same. However, the last time when this might have been worth discussing was probably 30 years ago, since by now changing `sum` to not use `0` as the default initial value  would break a lot code.