# Unable to make built-in function 'sum' work for an array of objects of my class

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, operator-overloading

I am unable to make the built-in function `sum` work for an array of objects of my class.

Here is an example of my attempt:

```
class string:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._new(other, str.__add__)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self._set(self + other)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def _set(self, other):
        self.data = other.data
        return self

    def _new(self, other, op):
        data = op(self.data, string._data(other))
        return string(data)

    @staticmethod
    def _data(other):
        return other.data if type(other) is string else other

a = string('a')
b = string('b')
c = string('c')
```

Executing `print(a + b + c)` prints the string `abc` as expected.

But executing `print(sum([a, b, c]))` throws:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'string'
```

Following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18136507/16004728), I have tried overriding function `__iter__` in various different ways, but no luck.

I have even added a `print` statement inside this function, but nothing was printed, implying that the function is not even executed when I execute `sum`.

Thank you for helping out :)

Comment: For start, don't use `string` as name - it's a module from standard library.

Comment: @buran: Oh, I wasn't aware of that, sorry. The above is just an example of a much larger class that I am working on (with a different name of course). I quickly wrote this one, in order to post a minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why there's a start argument in python's built-in sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543129/why-theres-a-start-argument-in-pythons-built-in-sum-function).

Comment: Looking at your example, I really don't see what the purpose of `_new`, `_add` and  `_data` is.

Comment: @buran: Thank you for the feedback. The purpose of `_new` and `_data` is to support the arithmetic operators (implemented via `__add__` and `__iadd__`) to handle both `str` operands and `string` operands.

Comment: My point is you can basically do the same inside the `__add__`, __iadd__`, without additional "internal" functions.

Comment: @buran: In my actual class, I am implementing all of the arithmetic operators, not just `+` and `+=`, and I want each operator to support both types of input operands. So I've found that encapsulating the type checking inside a single function (named `_data`) makes for a better code reuse.